# Adding values to a combobox based on another value VBA

Tags: vba, combobox

I am currently trying to get a combobox to add items based on another combobox value, but am coming unstuck.

The following is the code I have so far - through trial and error I have got to this stage, although this is still giving me a "1004"  error relating to the last line of the code. Is there a better way of writing this to get the same result?

```
Private Sub ProductInfo1_Change()

Dim strName As String
Dim strNameProductAllData As String
Dim strNameProductName As String
Dim strNameProductDescription As String

strName = Replace(OrderForm1.OrderFrm3.Value, " ", "")
    sheet = "strName"
strNameProductName = Replace(strName, " ", "") & "productname"

strNameProductDescription = Replace(strName, " ", "") & "productdescription"


    Me.ProductInfo2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets(strName).Range(strNameProductDescription), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ProductInfo1.Value, Sheets(strName).Range(strNameProductName), 0))

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning to the wrong object.

You are trying to set a combobox, ProductInfo equal to a range.

What you want to do is use the "RowSource" property of the combobox

For example:

```
  Me.ProductInfo2.RowSource = "mySheet!$A$1:$A$10"
```

This would make the choices for the ProductInfo2 combobox the items in cells A1-A10.

It is unclear what you are trying to get with the Match/Index Worksheet functions.  If the contents of the cell have a range, then just use the contents to be equal to this rowsource.  So for instance, if the column that represents "strNameProductDescription" has the range "myRange" in it, then your code can simply be modified to put this into the RowSource property.  If it contains some other piece of information, then you need to construct the range you are looking for so that it would be similar to the line shown above.  If myRange is a range on your worksheet, then the code,

```
  Me.ProductInfo2.RowSource = "myRange"
```

will work.

Comment: Opies, Thank you for your reply.

ProductInfo1 contains a list of products - which are under different sheets - thus the need for a dynamic range - Thus when I select the product I want ProductInfo2 to give me the data that matches it - however I have several items which are the same product but have different dimensions.

Hopefully this helps you to help me.

Thank you.

Comment: What is in the cell you are looking up?  Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ProductInfo1.Value, Sheets(strName).Range(strNameProductName), 0) is finding the value in your product info combobox in the range of the product in the specified sheet and returning either the row or column, I assume column.

Comment: Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets(strName).Range(strNameProductDescription), X) is getting the cell from the range with the ProductDescriptions in it, matching the row that you found previously.  What is the value in this cell?  Is it the name of a range that contains the values you wish in productInfo2, such as "product1range", is it the cells in a string, such as "$C$4:$C$50"?

Comment: The Index(x, Match) formulation is returning a cell.  The main problem you are having is that you need to put something into the .RowSource property.  That something depends on what you have in indexed cell, but it shouldn't be too difficult to manipulate it to what you need.

Comment: thank you again for your detailed feedback. I have started to look into this and have stumbled upon cascading comboboxes - which is what I was trying to achieve with the code above. Thus the look up cell is always dynamic dependant on the user form input. I will happily send you the entire file if this might help explain it!

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I can make such comboboxes.  I don't know exactly how you are doing this, but if you run into specific problems, feel free to post another question.